Can $\sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi i x n^n}=O(1)$ as $N\to\infty$?
Let $x$ be an irrational real number. Can the partial sums
$$\sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi i x n^n}$$
be bounded as $N\to\infty$?
This is not a homework problem, it is not inspired from a particular text either. Thus, I don't know how difficult this is or what tools one may use. There are various reasons why I demand $x$ to be irrational. For the values $x=1/2, 1/18,1/50, 1/54, 1/98$ the sum is bounded. For $x$ rational, say $x=a/d$ with $(a, d)=1$, the partial sums are $A\frac{N}{d\varphi(d)}+O(1)$ where $A=\sum_{n=1}^{d\varphi(d)} e^{2\pi i x n^n}$. This is because $n^n$ is periodic mod $d$, with period dividing $d\varphi(d)$. Thus, the partial sums are bounded if and only if $A=0$. This is a finite check, and it might even be possible to find a precise arithmetic criterion that tells exactly when $A=0$ (see this MathOverflow post for a similar problem). But this is more of a number theory/algebra question, and the methods are probably very different from the case where $x$ is irrational.
I am comfortable with (basic) calculus/analysis, analytic number theory, and some ergodic theory. I am aware of theorems like Weyl's equidistribution criterion.
I will keep thinking about the problem, if I come up with something, I will edit the post.

@Mike No. I'm just not sure what to do. I'm now trying to suppose x can be written as sum a_n/n^n with a_n integers. It is possible that you can always do that, not completely sure.

@Mike In my opinion, it's a bit disrespectful to assume what the origin of my question is (it's just pure curiosity). I would -1 you too, if I could.  If I didn't elaborate is because, as I said, I don't know what to do, and I don't know where to find hints for this problem. Should I instead have written a wall of nonsense so that you are convinced that I thinked about this problem for more than 5 minutes?

@Croqueta Note that this site's etiquette dictates that users should provide some context for their questions, including (for instance) the origin of your question and what you've tried so far

@Croqueta That doesn't mean writing a wall of nonsense, but that does mean giving us some sense of what you've tried so far. Also, telling us whether this is a homework question gives us a sense of whether we should expect any success the usual tools for looking at series like this

@Mike Ending your comment with "-1 and Vote-To-Close" is rude

@BenGrossmann That's a good point, but why would Mike so baldly assume this is a homework problem? Assuming that I didn't know what to try and that I came up with this question on my own (in the sense that it is not inspired by a particular passage of a book or lecture, so that I have no obvious tools at my disposal), would it have been better that I wrote that, and would have that sufficed as enough context?

@Croqueta Would that have sufficed? To my taste, yes, but it depends who you ask. A further bit of context that would help is telling us what tools you're aware of that don't apply in this situation (but that would apply to a simpler version of the problem). Not a comprehensive list of course, but enough for us to get a sense of your mathematical maturity. For instance, it would be useful to know whether you're aware of the equidistribution theorem.

@BenGrossmann If I'm am going to provide more context, should I edit this post or delete it and open another one?

@Croqueta Well, the question isn't closed yet so I think editing this one should be fine

Thank you OP for the edits, this looks challenging and interesting. +1 and Close-Vote-Retracted

@Croqueta For better or worse, the default assumption on this site is that OP is posting homework in bad faith, regardless of the quality or originality of the question. You need to prove that you aren’t doing so. I see you’ve given some good reasoning as to why you are posting in good faith.

Notation: $\{\cdot\}, [\cdot]$ denote the fractional part and floor function respectively.
Not an answer,  but just to record some ideas:
A curious formula:
Consider the tautological formula
$$\log_b y = z + \log_b(\frac{y}{b^z}),$$
valid for positive reals $b, z, y$.
Now let $X > 0$ be a large number. By setting $z := \log_b [X]$ and $y = \{X\}$, we obtain
$$\log_b \{X\} = \log_b [X] + \log_b \frac{\{X\}}{[X]}$$
which upon rearranging for $\{X\}$, yields
$$\{X\} = [X] b^{\log_b \{X\} - \log_b [X]}. \, [\text{Equation }1]$$
The upshot is that Equation 1 shows how to recover data on $X$ mod $1$ from logarithmic data of of $X$ and $[X]$.
For large $X$, we may safely ignore the floor function in $[X]$ on the outside to get
$$\{X\} = Xb^{\log_b \{X\}  - \log_b [X]} + O(1/X).$$
A possible application?
[To be continued…]
